# Why Do I Get List Indices Error When Changing How My Functions Are Called

Tags: python, jython

This method is grabbing data from an API, and using a library I partially wrote called CAP. It takes three parameters the first two of which are dates, the third being an empty list to return data to.

```
    def getData(startDate, endDate, dataList):
        apiData = CAP.apiGet(9,startDate,endDate)
        
        for data in apiData:
            customer = CAP.dive(data, ['customer'])
            sName = CAP.dive(data, ['sName'])
            date = system.date.parse(CAP.dive(data, ['date']).replace('T', ' '))
            pounds = CAP.dive(data, ['lbs'])
                
            dataList.append([customer, sName, date, pounds])
        dataList.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
        return dataList
```

This method is used to create USABLE data by removing outliers that don't quite meet the conditions specified by a dictionary that is set outside of the program and pulled in through the CAP library. rowsData is dataList from the previous method, and tempRow is another empty list which now that I think about it I don't need because I can modify rowsData in place.

```
    def createData(rowsData, tempRow):
        weekAmount, total = 0, 0
        for idx, row in enumerate(rowsData):
            try:
                pounds, customer, product = row[3], row[0], row[1]
                rowDay, nextRowDay = row[2], rowsData[idx+1][2]
            except IndexError:
                tempRow.append(weekAmount)
            if customer == data['Customer'] and product == data['Product'] or product == 'All Products':
                weekAmount += pounds
                total += pounds
            if rowDay == nextRowDay:
                continue
            if STD.isoWeek(rowDay) < STD.isoWeek(nextRowDay):
                tempRow.append(weekAmount)
                weekAmount = 0        
        return [tempRow, total]
```

After all is said and done this is the method that actually puts everything together.

```
    def setupData():
        dt = system.date
        sumColumns, sumRows = [['WeekNumber'], ['lbs2020'], ['lbs2021'], ['lbs2022'], ['lbs2023'], ['Average']], []
        totalColumns, totalRows = [['total2020'], ['total2021'], ['total2022'], ['total2023']], []
        years = (dt.getYear(dt.now()) - 2020)
        
        yearData = []
        for year in range(years+1):
            year += 2020
            if year != 2023:
                startDate, endDate = STD.isoW01(year), STD.isoW01(year + 1)
            else:
                startDate, endDate = STD.isoW01(year), system.date.now()
            yearData.append(createData(getData(startDate, endDate, []), [])) 


        totalRows.append([yearData[0][1], yearData[1][1], yearData[2][1], yearData[3][1]])
        for i in range(53):
            if i < len(yearData[3]):
                count = sum(1 for year in yearData if year[0][i] > 0)
                sumRows.append([i+1, yearData[0][0][i], yearData[1][0][i], yearData[2][0][i], yearData[3][0][i], count])
            elif i < 52:
                count = sum(1 for year in yearData[:3] if year[0][i] > 0)
                sumRows.append([i+1, yearData[0][0][i], yearData[1][0][i], yearData[2][0][i], 0, count])
        sumRows.append([53, yearData[0][0][52], 0, 0, 0, 1])            
        data['Sums'] = system.dataset.toDataSet(sumColumns, sumRows)
        data['Total'] = system.dataset.toDataSet(totalColumns, totalRows)
    setupData()
```

This line works perfectly fine.

```
mtdData = structureData(getData(start, end, []), [])
```

However, when I switch it up like this

```
data = getData(start, end, [])
mtdData = structureData(data, [])
```

It doesn't seem to work and wants to give me a finalizeDataTypeError: list indices must be integers
The block of code referencing mtdData is as such

```
data["Total"] = system.dataset.toDataSet([["mtdTotal"]], [[mtdData[1]]])
```

Does anyone know why you can do it the first way but not the second as it throws an error?

I've already tried printing out mtdData after switching the statements
when I do

```
print(mtdData)
```

For both I get 
`([[Date_Here, Some_Data]], Some_Data)`

I am trying to reference the first index of the tuple and because both the ways of structuring mtdData print the same thing out I am at a loss as to why it wouldn't work especially when the first index will always be the same.

Comment: Without seeing what `getData()` and `structureDate()` do, how are we supposed to guess what's wrong?

Comment: Is the variable `data` used by anything else in the code?

Comment: @Barmar No data is localized and cannot be referenced by anything outside of the current function. getData() and structureData() work as intended the error isn't there, the issue is that while outputting the same thing the program seems to not understand the second method of setting up the data. I just need to know if anyone knows why that reference isn't valid?

Comment: Please post a [mre] and the full traceback of the error.

Comment: @Barmar posted a minimal reproducible example. and the full traceback is quite literally finalizeDataTypeError : list indices must be integers

Comment: @Azur_Was_here Python errors always include at least a line number indicating where the error originated, if unsure, post literally everything that you see as output when running the program

Comment: @Azur_Was_here in `setupData()`, you assign `data['sums']` and `data['total']` but you don't initialise `data` itself. Are you sure that `data` is local to the function? One would expect an undefined name error if it really was.

Comment: Anyway, both the methods you show result in the same value being assigned to `mtdData`. The difference between them is that method 2 has the side effect of setting the value of `data`, while method 1 does not. So if your overall program works correctly with method 1 but not with method 2, it's very likely that the variable `data` is relied on elsewhere in your program, and so the side-effect of method 2 is causing your problem.

Comment: @slothrop that is exactly what is going on, make that an answer so I can pick it. Data is initialized inside the program but it is not a variable that can be changed. I am trying to change a constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we compare:

Code A:

```
mtdData = structureData(getData(start, end, []), [])
```

with Code B:

```
data = getData(start, end, [])
mtdData = structureData(data, [])
```

Both of them set `mtdData` to the same thing. But the difference between them is that code B has the side effect of setting the value of `data`, while code A does not.

So if your overall program works correctly with code A but not with code B, it's very likely that the variable `data` is relied on elsewhere in your program, and so the side-effect of code B is causing your problem.

(If you're doing this inside a function, and `data` is a global variable, then its global value won't change, but all subsequent code within the function itself will use your new locally assigned value of `data`.)

If you prefer to use two lines (like Code B), you can - just make sure to choose a variable name that isn't used elsewhere. Something like:

```
temp_data = getData(start, end, [])
mtdData = structureData(temp_data, [])
```